# Uncertain behaviour of _.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, underscore.js

```
let a = {
   b  : null
}

_.get(a, 'b',''); //return null
```

but

```
_.get (a, null, '') //return ''
```

Is null a falsy value for _.get()?

```
let a = {
   b  : {c:{
}
} //basically a nested object
```

I'm trying to do `_.get(a, 'b.c','').toString()` and I'm getting error because _.get return null. What is the best readable way to write this?

Comment: Are you actually using Underscore or Lodash? Lodash has broken its interface a couple of times, so they are not interchangeable nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument `defaultValue` will only be returned for `undefined` resolved values, not `null`. [see docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

If you want a fallback value for `null` or `undefined`, use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```js
(_.get(a, "b.c") ?? "").toString()
```

Below are different results using different mechanisms in defining default value:

```js
let a;

a = { b: null };
_.get(a, "b", ""); // null
_.get(a, "b") ?? ""; // ""
_.get(a, "b") || ""; // ""

a = { };
_.get(a, "b", ""); // ""

a = { b: undefined };
_.get(a, "b", ""); // ""

a = { b: 0 };
_.get(a, "b") || ""; // ""
_.get(a, "b") ?? ""; // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```js
_.get(a, 'b','');
```

you ask for the property `a['b']`, which happens to be `null`, which isn't `undefined`, so you get `null` as the final result. Next, in

```js
_.get(a, null, '');
```

you ask for the property `a['null']`, which doesn't exist, so it's `undefined`, and you end up with the fallback value `''`. Finally, with

```js
let a = {b: {c: {}}};
_.get(a, 'b.c', '');
```

you seem to be asking for `a['b']['c']`, which would be an empty object. However, the dotted path notation is Lodash-specific. If you are using Underscore, the path is interpreted as `a['b.c']` by default, which doesn't exist and is `undefined`. In that case, you should get `''` as the final result. I see no way this expression could result in `null`, even if you are using the original value of `a = {b: null}`.

If you are, in fact, using Underscore and you want to retrieve the nested `c` object within the `b` property, you have two options. Firstly, you can use array path notation, which is portable between Underscore and Lodash:

```js
_.get(a, ['b', 'c'], '');
```

Secondly, you can override `_.toPath` to enable dotted path notation for all Underscore functions:

```js
const originalToPath = _.toPath;
_.toPath = function(path) {
    if (_.isString(path)) return path.split('.');
    return originalToPath(path);
}

_.get(a, 'b.c', '');
```

I wouldn't recommend this, because it can break code that is trying to retrieve properties that contain the period character `.` in the name. I mention it for completeness; use your own judgment.